# magento age verification on create account page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento installation where I have activated the date of birth field on the create account page.

I need to add age verification to this to ensure all registered users are over the age of 16. Is there an option in the admin area for this or does it require some programming?

Comment: Search "magento age verification" on google, you'll find lots of answers

Comment: Thanks but I have looked previously and although there are many people asking the question there are no clear responses or information on how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following script for this validation may be it's help you.

```
<script>
function check_dob()
{
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    var dbDate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dbDate);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
    }

    if(age<=20)
    {
        alert("You are under "+age+" Year")
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can please this script in your register.phtml file

Comment: thanks Hardik I have tried this on the register.phtml file and the dob.phtml widget file but there is no change to the form.

Comment: Make sure your file is comming from
customer/form/register.phtml
or
persistent/customer/form/register.phtml  Dont forget to clear your cache.

Comment: thanks Hardik I am placing this under persistent/customer/form/register.phtml and placing this new code at the bottom of the form and cleared cache but still no change

Comment: are you working on local or live? if live please give me your url

Comment: You have to call check_dob() function in your Submit button. this is just script. you cant get any changes after putting only this script.

Comment: I am working locally so wouldn't be able to provide a link. Any other ideas of why this might not be working?

Comment: thanks, I am fairly new to programming. How do I call this function on the submit button?